# java.awt.Desktop::open() throws error "The system cannot write to the specified device"

Tags: java, desktop, ioexception

I have production code who, for one user, this line of code keeps throwing an error:

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.open(file);
```

Log file shows this as the error:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to open C:\Users\flast\Desktop\spreadsheet.xls. Error message: The system cannot write to the specified device.
```

I am unable to reproduce this error so I cannot provide a SSCCE. But, can anyone shed light as to why `Desktop::open()` would throw this error? Namely, why is it trying to "write" anything? `Desktop::open()` should only find the associated program and open the file. There's nothing to write.

Noteworthy: I actually **catch** this error in my code and try `Desktop::browse()` instead:

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
try {
    desktop.open(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    handleError(e);
    desktop.browse(file.toURI());
}
```

but `browse()` also throws an error:

```
Failed to open file:/C:/Users/flast/Desktop/spreadsheet.xls. Error message: Access is denied.
```

So I'm stumped.

Comment: It may not be `Desktop` that is actually generating the error, but it may be merely responding to an error(s) returned by the OS

Comment: Looks like a file permission issue.  Does file.length() return a positive value?  Does Files.size(file.toPath()) succeed?

Comment: I'll have to add it to the logged data to see. Again, I can't seem to reproduce the problem..